# Golang: custom template function "capture"

Tags: function, templates, go

I want to write template function like `Smarty's` `capture`.
How can I capture html inside

```
{{capture}}
    ...
{{/capture}}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{define "T1"}}ONE{{end}}
{{define "T2"}}TWO{{end}}
{{define "T3"}}{{template "T1"}} {{template "T2"}}{{end}}
{{template "T3"}}
```

ONE TWO

Answer (score -1):

You would do it in the application: Use a template for the HTML snippet you want to capture, render it, save it to a string and use it in subsequent template rendering.